# A problem with the implementation of FLUTTER project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When I implement a flutter project that consume all RAM that are 8 GB, knowing that I use a VS code  and implement it on my device not on an  simulator

Comment: Please provide additional details and clarifications: what is the flutter project doing and using in terms of libraries / technologies, what is the exact error or undesired effects that you have encountered etc.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code before running your project, use flutter clean command.

```
flutter clean
```

Issue mentioned here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40243